# 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'backup'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, anaconda

I have a program that migrates data from a Microsoft Access database to a local sqlite database. It runs on a 32-bit Miniconda installation rather than the usual 64-bit version I use because the Access version is 32-bit. I reinstalled that 32-bit miniconda installation this morning after something happened with my IT department that moved some of anaconda's program files. The clean install seems to be working fine, but I'm getting a bizarre error message when I try to backup the sqlite database.

Calling `sqlite3.Connection.backup` raises the following error: `'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'backup'`.

Except, of course, a `sqlite3.Connection` object *does* have an attribute called `backup`.

And, to make things even stranger, the file *is* being backed up. I can see a new file being created, but it's still throwing this error.

Here's a simplified version of the code that's causing the error:

I have a module called `db` that contains classes for connecting to both databases I have:

```
class SQL:
    def __init__(self, alt_path=None):
        if not alt_path:
            pdir = Path("C:\\path\to\default\project\directory")
            dbdir = pdir / "Data" / "db" / "SQL"
            sql_path = dbdir / "jjp.db"
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(sql_path.as_posix())
        else:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(alt_path.as_posix())
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        self.table_names = [
            table[0]
            for table in self.cursor.execute(
                "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"
            )
        ]

    def backup(self, backup_con):
        self.conn.backup(backup_con, pages=0)
        backup_con.close()

    def close(self):
        self.conn.close()
```

I'm importing those classes in a module called `backup`:

```
from jjp import db


def create_backup_con(db_type):
    today = datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    if db_type == "sql":
        db_file = sql_backup_dir / f"jjp_backup_{today}.db"
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file.as_posix())
        return conn
    elif db_type == "access":
        db_file = acc_backup_dir / f"jjp_backup_{today}.accdb"
        return db_file


def backup_sql():
    sql = db.SQL()
    bck = create_backup_con("sql")
    sql.backup(backup_con=bck)
    bck.close()
    sql.close()
```

Here's the full error message output:

```
backup.backup_sql()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 backup.backup_sql()

c:\users\path\to\backup.py in backup_sql()
     38     sql = db.SQL()
     39     bck = create_backup_con("sql")
---> 40     sql.backup(backup_con=bck)
     41     bck.close()
     42     sql.close()

c:\users\path\to\db.py in backup(self, backup_con)
    159         """
    160 
--> 161         self.conn.backup(backup_con, pages=0)
    162         backup_con.close()
    163 

AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'backup'
```

Running python 3.6.10 32-bit miniconda distribution on a 64-bit machine running Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Running python 3.6.10

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html), support for the sqlite backup functionality was added in Python 3.7. Indeed, if you look at the [3.6 version of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html), you'll see the description of the method is missing.

You'll have to use a newer Python release or find a different approach. Maybe [`VACUUM INTO`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) if using sqlite 3.27 or newer.

Comment: Thank you. I think when I created a new env after installing I just accidentally typed `python=3.6` rather than `python=3.7` so I didn't even realize it.